# How only 1 checkbox can be allowed to check in the group of checkboxes in Webforms

Tags: webforms

I have added a set of options yes,No, Sometimes with the type checkboxes.But
the user is supposed to tick only one checkbox.When I disable multiple selections for the field, by default it considers it as radio buttons. The radio buttons are ideal for this.But the requirement is checkboxes only. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: UI wise it makes no sense to use checkboxes for this. An option can never be 'yes', 'no' and 'sometimes' at the same time. Can't you tell the client that radio's are designed for this? Or 'cheat' it by using some CSS to make your radio's look a bit more like checkboxes? (See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279421/can-you-style-an-html-radio-button-to-look-like-a-checkbox) Using JavaScript or form submission callbacks will get hackish and is doomed to break at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Tell your client that radio buttons ARE checkboxes where the user can only select one option. You are therefore satisfying the requirement. See [this simple explanation](https://delib.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203430309-Radio-button-vs-checkbox-what-s-the-difference-) that you can pass along to your client. I would also look at @Neograph734's suggestion that you use radio buttons (as they are semantically correct based on the requirements you have) but make them look like checkboxes using CSS as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279421/can-you-style-an-html-radio-button-to-look-like-a-checkbox). That should avoid any pushback from your client and get you the functionality you need.

You can also point out to your client that if you start messing with javascript to use actual check boxes but limit the user to only checking one that you run a high risk of making your site no longer accessible to people with disabilities. Its very complicated to make js work in that way and remain accessible.

Time to educate your client :)